# scale SVG pathPoints

Tags: svg, path

I am scaling a polygon and set the actual scaled points into the pathArray

```
const pointsCal = this.findPoints(allocatedTable.tableType.shape.pathArray);//calculating max x,y min x,y of pathArray
    const diameterX = (pointsCal.highX - pointsCal.lowX)/2;
    const diameterY = (pointsCal.highY - pointsCal.lowX)/2;
    const scalex = (diameterX + this.settings.tableTableSpace) / diameterX;
    const scaleY = (diameterY + this.settings.tableTableSpace) / diameterY;
pathArray.forEach((point) => {
      if (point.command !== 'z') {
        point.x -= tableCenterPoint.x;
        point.y -= tableCenterPoint.y;
        point.x *= scalex;
        point.y *= scaleY;
        point.x += tableCenterPoint.x;
        point.y += tableCenterPoint.y;[enter image description here][1]
      }
    });
```

but for the regular rectangle it is working properly but for the rotated Shapes it is not scling propely

I think I had made a mistake in  logic in calculating scale X and scaleY value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the divide by 2?

Try something like this:

```
const width = pointsCal.highX - pointsCal.lowX;
const height = pointsCal.highY - pointsCal.lowY;
const scalex = this.settings.tableTableSpace / width;
const scaleY = this.settings.tableTableSpace / height;
```

If that doesn't work, then you'll need to provide a [minimal workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

**Update**

I'm still not 100% sure what you want. But looking at the code, I assume you are wanting to scale the original shape so that it fills the SVG.  But also allowing for some padding around it.

If so, you'll want to do something like this:

```
  DrawScalledRectangle() {
    // Get the size of the original polygon
    const bbox = this.tableGroup.getBBox();
    // Get the size of the <svg> element.
    // This will be the value at the time this function is run. But the <svg> has width
    // and height of "100%" so it may change if the window is resized.
    const mainSvg = document.getElementById("mainSVG");
    const svgWidth = mainSvg.clientWidth;
    const svgHeight = mainSvg.clientHeight;

    // The scale will be svgSize / originalSize (but we subtract the padding from the svgSize first)
    const scaleX = (svgWidth - this.tableTableSpace * 2) / bbox.width;
    const scaleY = (svgHeight- this.tableTableSpace * 2) / bbox.height;


    this.pathArray.forEach(point => {
      if (point.command !== "z") {
        // New point location = padding + (oldPoint - shapePosition) * scale
        point.x = this.tableTableSpace + (point.x - bbox.x) * scaleX;
        point.y = this.tableTableSpace + (point.y - bbox.y) * scaleY;
      }
    });
    console.log(this.pathArray);
    ...snip...
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thb9w5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank you, can you help with why we subtract y value from X value for heightconst height = pointsCal.highY - pointsCal.low;

Comment: That's a typo, from your original code, that I missed.  I have fixed it now.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3ivot, as you asked me, have simplified the code but the above logic is not working for me can you help me to scale uniformly

Comment: uniformly in the sense allocate same space between edges

Comment: thank you so much but I need to set the shape into the CenterPoint of shape that is scalled,then the padding will be same for all edges of the shape

Comment: So you want a shape that is exactly N units inset or outset from the current shape?  Like this: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_inset/?  That is not too difficult for edges that are lines, but arcs and bezier curves are quite tricky.

Comment: yes exactly like this cant we use scaling for that because it is a path element ,

Comment: That's not really possible using scaling.  You need to use a more involved algorithm like the one I linked to above.

Comment: One thing I will point out though is you can achieve insets and outsets using masks.  If you only care about drawing the shapes, and don't actually need the adjusted point coordinates, then you can do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cysdz84j/

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation , yeah I need the adjusted points.

Comment: I have tried to implement the above method in SVG but I have some difficulties in implementation,@Paul LeBeau can you give me a guide to implementing this feature

Comment: I am happy to help. But I am still not sure what you want.  In my updated answer, did I guess correctly?  If so, add a [mcve] with your new code so we can see what you did wrong.  If I didn't guess correctly, please update your question with more detail.

Comment: I tried to implement alienryderflex.com/polygon_inset   but I could not understand the algorithm properly. I could not figure out how the insetDist is calculated.but it is passed as a parameter is there any tutorial to get the idea behind this.